# Плавное изменение opacity

Tags: javascript

Вопрос из области теории.
Почему такой код работает (прозрачность изменяется плавно):

```
function setOpacity() {
     var el = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
     var op = 0;
     setTimeout(function func() {
         if (op > 1)
             return;
         el.style.opacity = op;
         op += 0.1;
         setTimeout (func, 60);
     }, 60);    
}
```

А такой - нет (`opacity` через 60 мс просто становится равной 1):

```
function setOpacity() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
    var op = 0;
    while (op <= 1) {
        setTimeout(el.style.opacity = op, 60);
        op += 0.01;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором варианте есть сразу 3 ошибки:

1. Вместо передачи функции, которая должна будет выполниться позже, в качестве первого параметра в `setTimeout` вы передаёте результат выполнения присваивания `el.style.opacity = op`. То есть присваивание происходит **сразу же**, что делает `setTimeout` бессмысленным
2. **Все** вызовы `setTimeout` произойдут разом через 60 миллисекунд от запуска кода
3. Даже если исправить обе предыдущие ошибки, код всё равно не будет работать корректно, ибо на момент первого вызова `setTimeout` переменная `op` **уже будет равна 1**, и все `setTimeout`-ы будут устанавливать прозрачность в 1

После исправления всех ошибок код таки будет работать правильно:

```js
function setOpacity() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
    var op = 0;
    while (op <= 1) {
        (function(_op) {
            setTimeout(function() { el.style.opacity = _op; }, 60 + op * 600);
        })(op);
        op += 0.1;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setOpacity);
```

```css
.submenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu"></div>
```

Comment: При указании строки кода - интерпретатор динамически создает анонимную функцию с телом из данной строки. Думаю, что это не ошибка все же. Просто более правильным считается объявление функции в явном виде.

Comment: @DenisBubnov а вы проверяли эту гипотезу? Я не только не слышал о том, чтобы интерпретатор брал и на ровном месте оборачивал код в функцию (какое он на это имеет право?), но и практика это не подтверждает.

Comment: Не проверял, но читал это в документации по JS. Вот тут к примеру: [setTimeout](https://javascript.ru/settimeout) или тут: [setTimeout и setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval), поэтому и написал комментарий.

Comment: @DenisBubnov не, там речь о передаче **строки** (`String`), которую можно с помощью `eval` выполнить как код. И по тем же причинам что и сам `eval` это считается плохой практикой.

Comment: А, да-да-да, точно, **стока**, вы правы. В случае строки оно будет интерпретировано. Спасибо за пояснение. Плохая практика - это да.

Answer (score 1):

Причина того, что `opacity` через 60 мсек становится равной 1 - простая. Цикл `while` отрабатывает практически моментально, а значит, что все вызовы кода, внутри `setTimeout` будут запущены практически в одно время. С минимальным разрывом во времени, поэтому вы и видите сразу значение равное единице.

```js
function setOpacity() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
  var op = 0;
  
  while (op <= 1) {
    op += 0.01;
    debugger;
    setTimeout(el.style.opacity = op, 60);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="submenu"> Example </div>
</br>

<button onclick="setOpacity();"> Set opacity </button>
```

Если выполнять код вручную, с использованеим `debugger`, то вы увидите, как ваше `opacity` меняется не моментально.  В первом же случае вы рекурсивно вызываете `func` с задержкой 60 мсек, поэтому там плавно, чего не скажешь про `while`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// js  выполныется последовательно
// например где-то данная функция запустилась 
function setOpacity() {
  // хватает данный элемент
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")[0];
  var op = 0;
  // проверяет
  while (op <= 1) {
    // если условие соответствует 
    // то срабатывает setTimeout
    setTimeout(el.style.opacity = op, 60);
    // и уже после того как setTimeout отработал
    // а потомм уже выполняется то что ниже
    op += 0.01;
  }
}
```